# Can gcc build an executable without access to a required shared library?

Tags: gcc, compilation, shared-libraries

When building an executable, gcc requires the -l flag to list the shared libraries, even though they can be changed freely without recompiling the executable. Does gcc use that flag only to check if all the symbols are ok? Can I build the executable without performing this verification?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dlopen to load the dynamic library at runtime, and dlsym to get the pointer to the function you like to call.

Here is a sample http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Comment: Yes, I know, but that requires me to change the application.